# On the number of solutions of $\gcd\left({2n\brace n},105\right)=1$, over integers $n\geq 1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples

In this post we denote the Stirling numbers of the second kind as ${n\brace k}$. I present a variant of the problem showed in the penultimate paragraph of section **B33** of [1] (see also the cited bibliography of the book), for a different sequence from combinatorics. I don't know if next problem is the most interesting that one can evoke as a variant, but I'm curious about my question. Your comments are welcome.

Up to $3000$ the sequence of integers $1\leq n$ satisfying $$\gcd\left({2n\brace n},105\right)=1$$
are $1, 6, 762, 2520, 2521$ and $2526$ (see if you want my section *Details for the computational evidence and documentation*).

> **Question.** Is it possible to determine if our equation $$\gcd\left({2n\brace n},105\right)=1$$ has finitely many or infinitely many solutions for integers $n\geq 1$? **Many thanks.**

If it is very difficult, mainly I am asking about what work can be done about the **Question**.

**Details for the computational evidence and documentation.** My code was written in Pari/GP. Search in Internet *Sage Cell Server* and paste next codes choosing as Language *GP*. I say this line

`for (n = 1, 1000, if(gcd(stirling(2*n, n, {flag = 2}),105)==1,print(n)))`

or

`for (n = 2000, 3000, if(gcd(stirling(2*n, n, {flag = 2}),105)==1,print(n)))`

You can find also a *Pari-GP reference card* from some universities, searching these words in Internet.

### References:

[1] Richard K. Guy, *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, Unsolved problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag (1994).

Comment: It is welcome, that if some professor or user of this site MathOverflow wants to study/explore some of my problems posted in this site, that he/she can do it. 
Also I am especially interested in knowing how to improve the mathematical content of the problems that I propose, thus feel free to add comments.

Comment: Are you aware of Carl Pomerance's "Divisors of the middle binomial coefficient", particularly Section 4 (When is $\binom{2n}{n}$ relatively prime to $105$?); see https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/catalan5.pdf. According to Pomerance, this problem was posed by Ron Graham who offered 1,000USD for a solution.

Comment: Yes if I am right @Seva I was inspired in the same problem from Guy's book ([1]). Many thanks, and it is incredible 1000 USD!

Comment: 6642 and 6644 are the other two instances up to 10000.

Comment: Many thanks for your computational effort @FelipeVoloch